# One-one and onto map from $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can you tell any one-one & onto map from $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$?
I can prove that these have same cardinality but am unable to think of a mapping.

Comment: $f(x,y) = (x+y-1)(x+y-2)/2 + x = x' \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Can you see a snake in the chessboard fitting all cases?

Comment: How can you prove they have the same cardinality without knowing a mapping??

Comment: I am tempted to close this as a duplicate. But frankly, I don't feel this is worth the effort of finding one.

Comment: You don't need a function which is **both** one-to-one and onto. It is sufficient to find one function for each type, which is rather simple. For example: $f(x,y)=2^x\cdot3^y$ is one-to-one, and $g(x,y)=x$ is onto.

Comment: See the [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function).

Answer (score 5):

How about: $$h:\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\rightarrow \mathbb N,~(m,n)\mapsto 2^{m-1}(2n-1)$$

Comment: Hey, I just realized this connects to the "even-part/odd-part" solution of the folklore pigeonhole problem: given any collection of $n+1$ integers from the set $\{1,\ldots,2n\}$, there must be two such that one divides the other. Neat-o.

Answer (score 4):

A mapping is not obvious! Define $\phi(k)=1+2+ \cdots k=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$. $h(m,n)=\phi(m+n-2) +m$ is a bijection. It's on page $358$ of Bartle and Sherbert if you have it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my answer. It is 
[not original](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function)
 , of course (thanks to Noah Schweber for providing the link) -- I'll just be walking through one angle on the reasoning behind it. It's similar to the one that mich95 posted, but I was already partway through this when (s)he posted so I thought I might as well finish what I'd started!

There is *one* element $(m,n) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ such that $m+n = 0$ (namely, $(0,0)$). Map this to $0$.

There are *two* elements $(m,n) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ such that $m+n = 1$ (namely, $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$). Map these to $1$ and $2$.

(I'm sure you get the idea by now but let's just do one more.)

There are *three* elements $(m,n) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ such that $m+n = 2$ (namely, $(0,2)$, $(1,1)$, and $(2,0)$). Map these to $3,4,5$.

*In general*, the elements $(m,n) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ such that $m+n = k$ are $(0,k), (1,k-1), \cdots, (k,0)$. These will map to $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}, \frac{k(k+1)}{2} +1, \cdots, \frac{k(k+1)}{2} + k = \frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}-1$ under this scheme (easily verified by induction).

Let $\phi: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be the mapping described above. Then for $(m,n) \in \mathbb{N}$, we have

$$\phi(m,n) = \frac{(m+n)(m+n+1)}{2} + m$$

Comment: Notice that all we're really doing is zig-zagging through a lattice...

Comment: Also Ivan mentioned this approach in the comments to the original question. I only just saw it.

Comment: This is called the *Cantor pairing function* (although depending on the author, $m$ and $n$ may be switched): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function